# How to use JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T> with application code trimming enabled?

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I'm trying to figure out how to use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>` when application code trimming enabled. The compiler suggests I need to use an overload that takes a `JsonTypeInfo` or `JsonSerializerContext`. I searched the web for solutions, but could not find any. I found some relevant examples, but they appear to be too complicated for such a simple task and it lead me to believe I'm missing something important here.

- Are there any simple solutions to this problem?
- Should I ignore this warning?
- In what cases this code might break functionality?

The compiler says I need to `make sure all of the required types are preserved` to prevent breaking functionality in production. How can I do this?

**project.csproj**

```
  ...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Code**

```
using System.Text.Json;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      Thing thing = Parse<Thing>("{}");
    }
    public static T Parse<T>(string json)
    {
        T test = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
        return test;
    }
}

public struct Thing
{
  public int Key1 { get; init; }
}
```

**Error**

> Using member 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(string,
> System.Type, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions?)' which has
> 'RequiresUnreferencedCodeAttribute' can break functionality when
> trimming application code. JSON serialization and deserialization
> might require types that cannot be statically analyzed. Use the
> overload that takes a JsonTypeInfo or JsonSerializerContext, or make
> sure all of the required types are preserved.

Comment: Problem with most serializers is that they use reflection, which means the trimming analyzer cannot see that the object is in use. Do not ignore. `JsonTypeInfo` is an option, or the attribute `[DynamicallyAccessedMembers]`, see also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/app-trimming-in-net-5/

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you, sir! It's getting much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, but the warning is gone.

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      JsonTypeInfo<Thing> typeInfo = SourceGenerationContext.Default.Thing
      Thing thing = Parse<Thing>("{}", typeInfo);
    }
    public static T Parse<T>(string json, JsonTypeInfo<T> typeInfo)
    {
        T test = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, typeInfo);
        return test;
    }
}

public struct Thing
{
  public int Key1 { get; set; } = 0;
}

[JsonSerializable(typeof(Thing))]
internal partial class SourceGenerationContext : JsonSerializerContext { }
```